# Can I enter the UK for 3 months next year, after spending more than 5 months there this year?

Tags: uk, repeat-visits, mexican-citizens

I'm a Mexican citizen and don't need any kind of visa to travel to the UK. I can just travel with my passport and stay there for up to 6 months. I was in the UK for 5 months and 2 weeks, from February 1st to July 17th 2017. I was there visiting some friends and traveling around as well.

I would like to visit my best friend in 2018, from February 28th to May 28th, just 3 months. Will I be able to stay in the country again for this period of time? Of course, my friend could give me an invitation letter and prove that I'm staying with him for those 3 months, and that he will cover all my expenses.

Comment: How are you able to spend so much time away from home? The risk is that you will be seen as not tightly enough connected to Mexico, and having no need to return there.

Comment: You may also appear to be trying to establish residence by spending large amounts of time in the UK. If the border official thinks this is the case, you may be refused entry even if you have an invitation.

Comment: well i used to work on ships, not anymore, but i made my savings and i live with my parents back home so i dont need to spend in anything, thats why i can travel still, but after this season i want to take in england i want to star a new job in mexico